# Cordova build with merges folder contains EPERM error

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have a Cordova project that I am building in Visual Studio 2015. For the Android build I had to jump through hoops to get round the fact that source files are under version control, and hence read-only. The build sequence starts:

1. before_prepare hook to remove read-only attribute from existing platform folder files (required for development build to run)
2. Prepare part of build copies read-only files from root to platform
3. after_prepare hook to remove read-only attribute from platform folder files to allow build to run without EPERM errors

Now on the iOS build there is the added complexity of having a merges folder, and the build starts:

1. before_prepare hook to remove read-only attribute from existing platform folder files (required for development build to run)
2. Prepare part of build copies read-only files from root to platform
3. Next part of prepare copies over the merges folder, which fails with an EPERM error as some of the files to be replaced are still read-only

The build says it has succeeded, but contains

```
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EPERM):D:\My Project\platforms\ios\www\css/index.css
```

None of the files in the merges folder have been copied into the platforms\ios folder.

How have others solved this without either

1. Removing the read-only attributes of their root source files which are in source control
2. Abandoning the built in merges process and writing a hook to do it

Comment: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered build errors and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. rsalva [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Comment: @Ryan - I have emailed you to start this conversation. Cheers, Chris.